# ruby regex split on last occurance of character

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm a little stumped on this one and I'm also not still on 1.8 so I don't have lookahead.

I have a bunch of strings which can look like:

```
"a/b/c/d/e/f 1/2/3"
```

which I want to turn into:

```
"a/b/c/d/e" "f" "1/2" "3"
```

So basically I want it to split by the last slash before the beginning of whitespace. I feel like I can do this normally but split always seems to do weird things.

Comment: I don't see how your example constitutes "split by the last slash before the beginning of whitespace," which would actually yield the strings "a/b/c/d/e" and "f 1/2/3". What do you actually mean?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it correctly.  I mean that the last slash is what's being split on. Anyway the example I gave illustrates it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.8 lacks look*behind*, not look*ahead*! All you need is this:

```
str.split(/\/(?=[^\/]+(?: |$))| /)
```

This split pattern matches a) any slash that is followed by non-slash characters up to the next space or the end of the string, and b) any space.

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo s
   return [$1,$2] if s =~ /(.+)\/(\S)/
end

str = "a/b/c/d/e/f 1/2/3"
a = str.split /\s+/
a.collect { |e| foo e }.flatten

=> ["/a/b/c/d/e", "f", "1/2", "3"]
```

I broke down the split and collect. You could, of course, shorten this as needed.

Comment: Thanks that works well. out of curiosity is it not possible to do it with regex alone?

Comment: As glenn pointed out this is entirely possible. I have a personal fear of the overuse of regex, however. Having had to maintain, update, and revisit such constructs I always opt to use them only for what is needed - and even then I try to keep them simple.

Comment: A fair point, but to ponder it just a little further, in this case I think your version is not materially more straightforward from the perspective of a later code-maintainer encountering it. At least with the single-regexp version it's clear that the goal is to split the string, and if it fails, you know you have to fix this one regexp.

Comment: [continued] Your way it's not immediately obvious whether the split and collect bits are doing two parts of one conceptual action, or two different things, and if the string changes format and things break you won't immediately know whether the problem is in the split, the split's regexp, foo's regexp, or foo's returning of [$1,$2].

Comment: Like many things, I believe this is a matter of style, so there is no wrong answer. My take on it is this: anything that makes extending an existing solution easier is better. Your points about where the problem may lie are valid but condensing all of the possible areas of failure to a single expression do not change the fact that these areas exist. Furthermore, the chore of disseminating the single point of failure is all that much harder (can you do tracer-bullets from a regex?). To illustrate my point, consider an issue with the Ruby implementation of `shellwords` between 1.8 & 1.9

Comment: [continued] In 1.8, the implementation is a `case` statement with logical progression between states that can occur. In 1.9 there is a jumbo regular expression that handles most of the logic. The 1.9 version is broken. I just want to use `shellwords`, but in order to do that in 1.9 I have to spend several hours to break down that massive state machine and figure out how to add the one state that is missed. Making things worse, I didnt write the original regex so I have no working knowledge of its construction. I'm still using 1.8.